# I would like to use gas from a different ETH address to spend an ERC20 token - is it possible?

Tags: myetherwallet

I have ERC20 tokens (on addresses with no ETH ) and will require first funding the address with ETH and then sending the ERC20 tokens (2 total tx fees to be paid). I would like to cut this down to one transaction fee by publishing my ERC20 tx using gas paid from a different address with existing eth on it, is it possible?